# How to close a half filled hole after boolean difference?

Tags: modifiers, vertices

I have used a boolean modifier on my structure, thus willing to make a cylinder-shaped hole in it. For some reason I do not know, once I applied the boolean the two edges of the holes were only partially connected by vertices.

[[image: The whole is only filled halfway]]

From there on, what method could I use to bind the rest of the hole ?

Comment: Have you tried using the _Exact_ solver for the boolean?

Comment: Yes, it was set by default on *Exact*

Comment: There may have been problems with the cylinder mesh that you used for the cutout. The exact solver should be able to handle this just fine.

Comment: That may be right. Now the problem that I've got is I cannot go backwards anymore, that's why I'm trying to fix it from here on in order not to start the project anew.

Comment: If you're ok with having a slightly larger hole, you could just fill it with an n-gon and redo the boolean with a slightly bigger cylinder.